# What does this notation mean on this derivative question?

Tags: derivatives

$x^2 \tan x \mid _{x=\pi}$

What does this little line after the $\tan x$ mean? Does it mean I should take the derivative and then substitue in $\pi$?
I need to find the second derivative.

Comment: Should it be $x^2 \tan x \mid _{x=\pi}$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the crappy formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it usually means you should substitute in $\pi$ after you have taken the derivative.

It would help if you would write the entire expression.
Now and in the future.

Including the derivative.

Comment: This is the entire expression, I'm supposed to find the second derivative of this expression.

Comment: In what context is this?

Comment: There is no derivative to be taken here.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical bar and subscript just means substitution.  In this case $\pi$ is substituted for $x$.

$$\left.x^2 \tan x \right\vert_{x=\pi} \quad =\quad \pi^2\tan \pi \quad =\quad 0$$

*If* there's a differential involved, *then* perform that before the substitution.

$$\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d~x^2\tan x}{\mathrm d~x}\right\vert_{x=\pi}\quad=\quad 2\pi\tan\pi \;-\; \pi^2\sec^2\pi \quad=\quad \pi^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from history and the cumbersome nature of mathematical notation. The notation is asking for $f(\pi)$ where for all appropriate $x$, $f(x)=x^2\tan x$. Over the centuries, we got into the habit of describing a function by an expression in $x$, like “The function $x^2-\frac{\sin x}x$”, and then when we wanted to substitute a number for $x$, we didn’t have a good way of showing that substitution. The big vertical bar with subscript afterwards is cumbersome, and perhaps subject to ambiguity in some cases, but in simple situations, it can suffice.

Maybe I should say that if you insist on writing the derivative of $f$ as $\frac{df}{dx}$, then there really is no other way of denoting evaluation of the derivative than $\frac{df}{dx}\Big|_{x=a}$.